# Can't make three divs with background images responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, background-image

I have three divs that contain background images (`background-image: url()`) but I'm having issues in making them responsive (using bootstrap) and putting spacing between them. I tried some things like width: 100% and margin: 0 auto but adding the margin property kinda removes margin and images lose spacing between each other if margin is used while padding of course doesn't work. Also for some reason I cannot add width to the images only height.

http://codepen.io/skullscream-1471533661/full/jAooJB

I'd usually google this but this has got me so frustrated that I can't even think of what to google.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is excellent for making this sort of thing easy. [Here is a great resource for flexbox to learn from.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Here I've given the parent "display: flex" to make the children flex elements. I've made the children 32% wide (leaving a 1% gap). I've set the parent to "justify-content: space-between" to tell the flex elements to leave space between each item.

On mobile I've given the parent "flex-wrap: wrap" so that if they are too wide they'll drop to the next line, and children 100% width so they span the full width of the device.

Additionally for the background images to work properly with the fluid boxes I've given them "background-size: contain" and "background-position: center center". Ideally it would be better to use actual image tags for them.

Please note that flexbox doesn't yet have full browser support [(but it's still pretty good)](http://caniuse.com/flexbox), and you'll need to [add vendor prefixes as necessary.](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/)

```css
.projects {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.projects > div {
  flex: 0 1 32%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .projects {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .projects > div {
     flex: 0 1 100%;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
   }
 }
```

Comment: This one works for medium sized screens (760px) but not for large ones.
On larger ones it looks stretched. http://i.imgur.com/h6OLNdh.png

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to accomplish this:
1. Change your parent div style to this:

```
#my-projects-section {
    background-color: black;
    height: 500px;
    width:100%;
}
```

2. Add this to your child styles:

```
#image-one,
#image-two,
#image-three {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 1.66%;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: .2s ease-out, .2s ease-in;
}
```

http://codepen.io/westefan/pen/Lkoooq

Currently this is statically defined, if you would like to add a new project into the section, you have to modify the CSS. There are also options to calculate margins, but it is not yet supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc
Another option would be to use Javascript to count childelements and create style completely dynamical based on the amount of children.

Comment: I will need to add more another two sections unfortunately.

Comment: Also you should verify your email to have full view enabled on codepen :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on codepen, when you add two extra sections you just need to adjust the width and margin percentages as pointed out in my post.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks then buddy. :)

Comment: I'd upvote your comment but it says something about not being able to vote until I have 15 rep.